# What is the meaning of the error message "scheduler queue is full" in supercollider?

Tags: scheduling, supercollider

I am using a class that contains a function involving `TempoClock.default.sched` [I'm preparing an MWE]. If I make a new instance of the class and apply the function, I obtain following error message:

> scheduler queue is full.

This message is repeated all the time. What does it mean?

Comment: Replacing `TempoClock` by `AppClock` or `Systemclock` did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every clock has a queue to store scheduled events. The size of the queue is very large - but still limited (I think ~4096 items?). The "scheduler cue is full" error happens when this queue is full - this can either happen when you legitimately have more than 4096 events scheduled on a given clock. But, a common bug case is accidentally queueing events far in the future, such that they hang out in the queue forever, eventually filling it up. It's easy to do this if you, e.g. call .sched(...), which takes a relative time value, but try to pass it an absolute time (which would schedule the event far far in the future).

If you need to actually schedule more than 4096 events at a given time - I believe the Scheduler class has a queue that can be arbitrarily large. AppClock uses this scheduler, so it shouldn't have a problem with large numbers of events. However - the timing of AppClock is less accurate than SystemClock, and isn't good for fine-grained music events. If you need highly accurate timing, you can use multiple TempoClocks and e.g. use different ones for each instruments, or each different kind of event etc.

Comment: How come that the code works in a .scd file, but if I adapt it to a class (.sc file), it gives the error?